# Counting occurrences over all dates (not a specific date)

Tags: sql-server, datetime, count

I have this piece of code that counts the number of occurrences for a set of events on an hourly basis. I have it set up to calculate the count for all the hours where locate_received_date is 2016-12-01 (Note: locate_received_date data type is DATETIME with YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss format). I entered the date manually to count for the previous day. The code excerpt is below:

```
SELECT CAST(locate_received_date as date) AS 'ForDate', 
       DATEPART(hh, locate_received_date) AS 'OnHour', 
       COUNT (*) AS 'HourCount'
FROM   MyTable
WHERE  locate_received_date BETWEEN '2016-12-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2016-12-01 23:59:59.999'
GROUP BY CAST(locate_received_date as date), DATEPART(hh, locate_received_date);
```

Now the table "MyTable" has hundreds of rows worth of data for many different dates. I need to run the count for all distinct dates, not just manually entered specific ones. I was thinking I could nest the following somehow:

```
DISTINCT CAST(locate_received_date AS DATE)
```

Or perhaps do this using some kind of a FOR loop?

EDIT: 
Here's the script to create the table. There really isn't any other column worth creating. There is no ID or anything in the table. The table is being updated and every time there is an update, locate_received_date is update with the date and time of occurrence. I need to count first based on hours (which my script does), and also based on days.

```
 CREATE Table myTable(
   Locate_Received_Date date); 


INSERT INTO myTable(Locate_Received_Date) VALUES ('2016-12-01 15:14:07.000');
INSERT INTO myTable(Locate_Received_Date) VALUES ('2016-12-01 15:13:37.000');
INSERT INTO myTable(Locate_Received_Date) VALUES ('2016-12-02 15:13:37.000');
INSERT INTO myTable(Locate_Received_Date) VALUES ('2016-12-01 15:13:07.000');
INSERT INTO myTable(Locate_Received_Date) VALUES ('2016-12-02 15:12:08.000');
INSERT INTO myTable(Locate_Received_Date) VALUES ('2016-12-02 15:12:07.000');
INSERT INTO myTable(Locate_Received_Date) VALUES ('2016-11-28 15:11:37.000');
INSERT INTO myTable(Locate_Received_Date) VALUES ('2016-12-02 15:11:08.000');
INSERT INTO myTable(Locate_Received_Date) VALUES ('2016-12-02 15:11:07.000');
INSERT INTO myTable(Locate_Received_Date) VALUES ('2016-11-28 15:10:37.000');
INSERT INTO myTable(Locate_Received_Date) VALUES ('2016-11-29 15:10:08.000');
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I am not sure why the query you posted won't work for a date range spanning more than 1 date. From what I see this should work for just about any date range.

Comment: I wrote "WHERE  locate_received_date BETWEEN '2016-12-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2016-12-01 23:59:59.999", specifying just one day. I need this command to be more general so it can run for all dates in the database. I am in the process of editing my question to add my table

Comment: remove the WHERE clause then....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it is only counting one day is that the `where` clause specifies one day. If you remove the `where` clause and add an `order by`, I think you will accomplish what you are looking for. Let me know if your desired output differs from what this renders and I can update the query accordingly:

```
SELECT CAST(locate_received_date as date) AS 'ForDate', 
       DATEPART(hh, locate_received_date) AS 'OnHour', 
       COUNT (*) AS 'HourCount'
FROM   MyTable
GROUP BY CAST(locate_received_date as date), DATEPART(hh, locate_received_date)
ORDER BY CAST(locate_received_date as date), DATEPART(hh, locate_received_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it correct that you need to count occurrences for particular day with hour step? If so, then here is synthetic example:

```
with a as (select convert(datetime,'2016-12-01 00:01:00.000',120) s 
        union all
        select convert(datetime,'2016-12-01 01:02:02.000',120) s 
        union all
        select convert(datetime,'2016-12-01 00:03:03.000',120) s 
        union all
        select convert(datetime,'2016-12-01 03:04:04.000',120) s 
        union all
        select convert(datetime,'2016-12-01 00:05:05.000',120) s 
        union all
        select convert(datetime,'2016-12-01 06:00:00.010',120) s )
        ,
    b as(select convert(varchar(10), s,120) s
        , a.s dt
        , DATEPART(hh,s)onhour 
            from a )
select count(*)cnt, s, onhour
  from b
group by s, onhour
```

Applying to your data it would be:

```
with a as (select convert(varchar(10), locate_received_date,120)s
            , locate_received_date
            , DATEPART(hh,locate_received_date)onhour 
            from MyTable    
            )
select count(*)cnt, s, onhour
  from a
group by s, onhour
```

the main thing you must remember is the MS SQL Server conversion codes according to this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: Hi Yuriy! Thanks for the reply. The code for me is not working as I cannot feed locate_received_date into the SUBSTRING argument. It does not take date data type

Comment: I've changed my post. generally it is not so important to which side to convert data - from date to string or from strin to date

Answer (score 0):

Your locate_received_date is a *datetime*, not a date, right?  If so, then something like this should work:

```
select count(Locate_Received_Date)  from myTable
group by  
convert(varchar(10), cast(Locate_Received_Date as date), 112) + '_' +     
convert(varchar(2), DATEPART(hh, Locate_Received_Date))
```